# How Can I Classify <li> Tag Based When a Name in the Menu is Clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am new in MVC. I'm facing a little problem and I can not figure out how to do it.

When a name in the menu is clicked, I want the name of the class of the clicked `<li>` tag to be "active".

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Our Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

For example: When I click "Blog", I want it to be like this: `<li class="active"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>` or when I click "Store" `<li class="active"><a href="#">Store</a></li>`

Is there an easy way to do it? If it is, will you share with me if it will not bother you? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you look here or google for some C# MVC Basic's tutorials 
[Step by Step learning MVC Tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are looking to accomplish. But in the most common scenarios, clicking on a menu will take you to a particular page. When that page loads, it would normally set the menu item that corresponds to the current page as being active. That could be done server side while that page is being constructed.

Comment: @JonathanWood This scenario is too old to be considered anymore. With the modern techniques for partial page updating, it is no longer the case. For a solution check my answer.

Comment: Although you might coding against the ASP.NET using C#, the current problem has nothing to do with any server-side technologies; it is a pure client-side concern and is resolved by JavaScript.

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff You're saying a menu consisting of links is now obsolete? We'll just have to disagree on that. I think you'll find that approach is still used all over the Web. As far as your answer, I'm not seeing how that requires partial page updating. But, obviously, I agree that it's the right approach when you're menu items keep you on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `jQuery` you can make use of its [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) methods. But first you need to subscribe to the click event of the `<li>` elements. The `$(document).ready()` handler is the perfect place to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // narrow down the selector by specifying the parent ul element's id or class
    $("li").on("click", function(e) {
        var sender = $(e.target).closest("li");
        sender.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
        sender.addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a few line javascript code (After the menu) to check the url of the current page:

```
<div id='menu'>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>

var href = window.location.href;
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
if(href == 'SOME THING') 
   menu.children[0].className = 'active';
if(href == 'SOME THING ELSE') 
   menu.children[1].className = 'active'; ///.....
```

And if you have any relation between url and the text in links (Home, Our Menu, Blog ...) It colud be easier to fine the related menu...

To better understanding read "Jonathan Wood"'s comments under your question.